# HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed ( rest framework )

Tags: python, django, rest, backend

i learn some django code with rest framework and i get a problem
i try from model but i'm getting an error :
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
"GET /create-room HTTP/1.1" 405 12243
someone help me .
i will write  view.py , serializer.py and (urls.py in my app)
my code :

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer
from .models import Room
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


# Create your views here.


class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer


class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                            votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                room.save()
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room


class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('id','code','host','geust_can_pause',
        'votes_to_skip','created_at')


class CreateRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('geust_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip')
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RoomView, CreateRoomView
urlpatterns = [
    path('room',RoomView.as_view()),
    path('create-room',CreateRoomView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Did you define a GET endpoint for your API? That looks like a POST endpoint only? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Please post your serialisers.py and urls.py